# Bare ground inside conduit?

Tags: electrical, grounding, conduit, bonding

I'm finishing up the rough in wiring for a kitchen remodel, but I have a situation where I can't run cables through studs for a light switch because there is no wall cavity. I decided to run it strait up against the wall into the attic space through conduit. Its a short 5' run of conduit and just 90 degree stubs out into the attic then connects with the kitchen lighting circuit.

I ended up just stripping the romex back instead of using THHN because I needed the attic portion of the run to be sleeved (I'm aware of the lack of conductor labeling violation here, its just what I ended up doing in my own kitchen). The conduit does NOT connect back to the panel. Is having a bare ground inside conduit going to be an issue? Is this any different from having a ground connected to a metal box?

Any info would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: And I think the "right" way to do this would be a junction box at the top of the conduit, THHN through the conduit, NM connected to the THHN in that junction box and conduit itself as ground.

Comment: We often see people intentionally violate Code, saying "but that's OK, because the purpose of the rule is X".  And they are wrong; there are *several* reasons, but they only looked at the one most convenient to their plan-to-violate.    Another reason is the individual wire insulation of Romex isn't anywhere as near as tough as THHN.   That said, there's nothing wrong with using a stick of conduit as a damage shield for Romex *in its sheath*.

Comment: "It's just my own kitchen" - until you sell it